# SSIS - Write a log in existing package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I would like to include a log to check the DB source in existing package to track DB source details in different environments. This is existing package and I am totally new to SSIS. I am not sure how to implement in SSIS package.

Is there any built in functionality available in SSIS 2008?
It would be useful if there is any reference link.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging#server_logging

Comment: @MitchWheat - Thanks. Is there any reference link to write log manually.

Comment: What data do you want to "log"?